# How to inject global styles while rendering server-side with styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, serverside-javascript, server-side-rendering, styled-components

I couldn't figure this out from the [documentation](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#server-side-rendering).

I'm trying to add some global styles to my server side rendered React application via [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com) - but I can't figure out how to do this.

Here's parts of my `globalStyles.js`:

```
import { injectGlobal } from 'styled-components';

export default () => injectGlobal`
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico');
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400');
    html {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    *, *:before, *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }
`;
```

Here's my universally rendering express-handler:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const React = require('react');
const { renderToString } = require('react-dom/server');
const { StaticRouter } = require('react-router-dom');
const { ServerStyleSheet } = require('styled-components');

const { default: App } = require('../src/containers/App');
const baseStyles = require('../src/styles'); // How to get this in the global css

const indexFile = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build', 'index.html'), 'utf8');

function universalLoader(req, res) {
    const css = new ServerStyleSheet();
    const context = {};

    baseStyles();

    // Create the markup from the React application
    const markup = renderToString(
        css.collectStyles(
            <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url}>
                <App />
            </StaticRouter>
        )
    );

    const html = indexFile
        .replace('{{SSR}}', markup)
        .replace('{{CSS}}', css.getStyleTags());

    // Send the response back to the user
    res.send(html);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, calling `baseStyles()` (which in turn is calling `injectGlobal`) in my `<App />` component `render()` method fixed the problem. :)